# How can I figure out where Maven got an artifact from?

Tags: maven, nexus

I just spent half an hour working with a colleague to figure out why I could build a project when he (working from the exact same source) could not.  Common start to a story about Maven, I know.  Anyway, it turns out that we had a dependency on something like `org.apache.commons:commons-pool`, while the repo we pointed to only supplied `commons-pool:commons-pool`.  We both overlooked the difference for a long time until we finally caught on.  I must have been able to "see" the former, while he obviously could not.

So my question is: how can I ask Maven "where are you getting `X:Y` from"?

Bonus questions: If it's only showing up in the local cache, is there any way to tell how it got there?  Can I tell Maven "just this once, make sure everything you're using in the build is also available from my remote repo"?

Comment: If you just want to reload everything, there's dependency:purge-local-repository.  Otherwise, I'd consider renaming your local repo and creating a new empty one.  Then, if you have a problem, you still have your old local to see what you're missing.  I'm no expert, though!

Comment: Each artifact should have an associated checksum file. Make sure they match. Otherwise, just wipe the local repo for that dependency and try again.

Comment: Are you sharing a mirror?  If not, should you be?  If so, how did you get the right jar without it being loaded into the mirror?

Comment: To clarify, it's not a checksum-type issue, it's the fact that two artifacts had similar names and one was available from the shared repo, while the other was not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have repositories available on your settings.xml that your friend don't.

As Ed Staub said you can try to clean your local repository by executing:

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository
```

After that try to download all your project dependencies by running:

```
mvn dependency:go-offline
```

Now if you have a problem with the last goal saying it could not find for example the artifact `org.apache.commons:commons-pool` you can try to find its repository going to http://www.mvnbrowser.com and searching for this artifact, then on the results page you can select the tab **Repositories** to see where you can find this artifact (for example JBoss maven repo).

After getting the artifact group, id, version you can add the repository where it's located to your project by adding the current content to your pom.xml:

```
<repositories>
<repository>
<id>repository.jboss.org-public</id>
<name>JBoss repository</name>
<url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
</repository>
</repositories>
```

Then if you try to download the dependencies again it now should work.

```
mvn dependency:go-offline
```

Comment: so what the answer on the question how do I see how X:Y was brought into the project?  I need to see it's parent and it's parent to see what project brought that jar in right now as I need to exclude a jar that is causing issues.