# maven, how to find out where X:Y artifact came from?

Tags: maven-2

I didn't see a clear answer from the same question

[How can I figure out where Maven got an artifact from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613850/how-can-i-figure-out-where-maven-got-an-artifact-from)

I have a jar slf4j-log4j that is sneaking into our project via some other artifact.  In eclipse, I click on dependency hierarchy and see the jar there, I click on it and choose exclude from project which doesn't do anything....I try to right click and see if I can see it's parent that brought it into the project....nope.

How to see the graph of all parents from the artifact that was brought in?

This is all because maven doesn't seem to have global excludes like ivy does :( :( :( so I need to exclude this jar on that project that brought it in(and we have too many projects too look at each and every one).

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the command line, do:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=the.groupId
```

See: [`dependency:tree` mojo](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html)

And:

> I click on it and choose exclude from project which doesn't do
>   anything....

Are you using a current version of Eclipse with m2e? Because previous versions with m2eclipse could never do that, but m2e can.

Comment: yes, but the tab Dependency Heirarchy does NOT match the mvn dependency:tree which solved my problem as I found and excluded the jars AND there was no other tabs that helped.